# "fatal error: Array index out of range swift"

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

The code being:

```
class Singleton {

    class var sharedInstance:Singleton {
        struct Static {
            static var instance:Singleton? = nil
            static var token:dispatch_once_t = 0
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.token)
            {
                Static.instance = Singleton ()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    var prayerArray = Array<PrayerSound>()

}
```

and:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let prayer = PrayerSound(namazName: cellLabel, pathString: filePath!, checked: checked)
        sinleton.prayerArray[cellindex] = prayer

}
```

Comment: what is in your `–numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `–tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` methods' bodies?

Comment: the `dispatch_once` part is not needed at all. This singleton syntax uses `dispatch_once` automatically behind the scenes.

Comment: You are correct, but the error has nothing to do with the singleton - he's got an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initialising `prayerArray` as an empty array with the line `var prayerArray = Array<PrayerSound>()`. Therefore it has no elements. You have to either initialise it to have a certain length, or append items to it. I think what you want is to do is to initialise it to have enough elements to accept your indices. Something like

`var prayerArray = Array<PrayerSound>(count:64, repeatedValue: somePrayer)`

Alternatively, you can declare it as an array of optionals, and set them to `nil`:

`var prayerArray = Array<PrayerSound?>(count:64, repeatedValue: nil)`